# Make expanded notification bigger than 256dp on pre nougat devices

Tags: android, notifications

I have created an android notification which is being used as a "widget" and displays some buttons of a classic tv remote in order to control a TV. The thing is that this notification is being displayed correctly on android devices with nougat and oreo but not on prior versions.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_circle_line)
                    .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle())
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
                    .setOngoing(false)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Is there any way to stop the notification from being cropped on 256dp?

[image: The correct]

[image: The wrong]

Answer (score 0):

**Cause: For 5.0 Lollipop "Notification icons must be entirely white".**

If we solve white icon problem by setting target SDK to 20, our app will not target Android Lollipop, which means that we cannot use Lollipop-specific features.
**Solution for target Sdk 21**

If you want to support Lollipop Material Icons then make transparent icons for Lollipop and above version. Please refer following: [https://design.google.com/icons/](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)

Please look at http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html, and we'll see that the white style is how notifications are meant to be displayed in Android Lollipop.

In Lollipop, Google also suggest that we use a color that will be displayed behind the white notification icon. Refer Link: [https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)

Wherever we want to add Colors [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)][2]

Implementation of Notification Builder for below and above Lollipop OS version would be:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
    notification.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color););
} else { 
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
}
```

Note: setColor is only available in Lollipop and it only affect to background of the icon.

It will solve your problem completely!!

1. [https://design.google.com/icons/](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)
2. [https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)
3. [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)
4. [https://design.google.com/icons/](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)
5. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Comment: So what you telling me is that that my  notification layout is being cropped because my notification icons are not white? That's at least strange